# sanityClient says Module '"c:/Users/USER/Documents/..."' has no exported member 'sanityClient'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I already installed `npm i @sanity/client`

it still dosen't work

I created `export const sanityClient = createClient(config);` in **sanity.js**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { sanityClient } from '../../sanity'
import { Tweet } from '../../typings'
import { groq } from 'next-sanity'

const feedQuery = groq`
*[_type == 'tweet']{
  _id,
  ...
}| order(_createdAt desc)`

type Data = {
  tweets: Tweet[]
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const tweets: Tweet[] = await sanityClient.fetch(feedQuery)
  // console.log(tweets)
  res.status(200).json({ tweets })
}
```

This is where I tried to import sanity client.

Comment: How are you importing the `createClient`?

Comment: paste this in your sanity.js file import { createClient } from 'next-sanity';

    make sure you have next-sanity installed

Answer (score -1):

I already solved it

The problem was that i didn't put the sanity.js file in the main outer folder i put it in the sanity folder

Comment: Consider deleting the whole question, as the issue is file structure and nothing to do with code.

Comment: I agree with the commenter: this question should be deleted.